# ergonomic non-literal Python enums with type checks

Tags: python, enums

I'd love to know a better way to use Enums for control flow in python. The enum.Enum base class doesn't appear to support my use case; all values must be literals, with values declared in the enum class itself.

In 3.10, Python added support for a match statement that looks somewhat similar to Rust's. One of the most useful applications of match in Rust is to match against Enum variants at runtime. It's not obvious this is possible in python. I'd love to know better solutions (preferably with type checking) than my janky, verbose hack-around.

Eg. from a macro compiler i'm writing:

```py
class SizeCallEnum:
    # variants
    macro = None
    jumptable = None
    
    # constructor, either pass arguments like this, or as **kvargs without typechecks
    def __init__(self, name: str,
                 # `int` was actually another class, but setting to int for simplicity
                 macro: None | int, 
                 jumptable: None | int):
        assert name in ["MACRO", "JUMPTABLE"]
        assert macro is not None or jumptable is not None
        self._name_ = name
        match name:
            case "MACRO": self.macro = macro
            case "JUMPTABLE": self.jumptable = jumptable
```

Comment: Pretty sure the answer here is: This not a use case envisioned for Python `Enum`s; you'd use separate classes to represent wildly different types (Rust's enums are *far* more powerful and flexible).

Comment: Would a namedtuple of `(enum, value)` work for this?  That's closest I can think of to what you seem to be doing